# Appending div inside 'form' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm try to append 'div' element and its content inside an another 'div' but that's not working inside 'form' tag, outside its working fine ..

```
<form id="myForm">
            <div id ="wrapfields" class="input_fields_wrap">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <button style ="margin-left:1%;"class="btn btn-success"onclick="Addelemt()">+</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <label class="text-center">Add Items</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addItem[]" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2   form-group">
                      <label>Price</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addprice[]" id="email">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-2   form-group">
                     <label>Quantity</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addprice[]" id="email">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div id ="" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group" style="margin-left:45%;">
            <button  type ="submit" onsubmit ="return saveInputs()" name ="submit" class="btn btn-default"/>submit</button>   
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

and the javascript code written so far..

```
var counter = 0;var increment=0;

function Addelemt()
{   
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('wrapfields');  
    increment++;
    var divClass = document.createElement("div");
    divClass.setAttribute('id','divId'+increment);
    console.log(divClass);
    parentDiv.appendChild(divClass);

}
```

Can anyone tell me that why its not working inside 'form'???

Comment: Why do you increment in such a complicated way?

Comment: i changed it ..

Answer (score 3):

So, the problem is with your html

```
<button style ="margin-left:1%;" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Addelemt()">+</button>
```

add `type="button"` to Add button

```
<button style ="margin-left:1%; "class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="Addelemt()">+</button>
```

As `button` inside `<form>` tag without `type` attribute is treated like `Submit` button, hence it refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, thank you . i was wondering why the page is reloading while i click the '+' button.

Comment: @ARUNMadathil Welcome, Pleasure is all mine, You can accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Ahhh! I got that, no worries.

Comment: @ARUNMadathil No worries at all, you can accept it once you get enough reputation :)